# Почему не получается flipp эффект?

Tags: html, css, анимация

Что я делаю не так, почему у меня не выходит эффект?

```css
.product-card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200;
    perspective: 600;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.product-card:hover .product-card__flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

.product-card__flipper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}


.product-card__front-side, .product-card__back-side {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.product-card__front-side {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
}

.product-card__back-side {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    background-color: red;
}

.product-card__title {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='product-card'>
    <div class='product-card__flipper'>
        <div class='product-card__front-side'>
            <img class='product-card__image' src='' alt='asd' />
            <h3 class='product-card__title'>asdasd</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='product-card__back-side'>
            <p class='product-card__image'>asd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы написали .product-card__back-side {
    transform: rotate(-180deg); а нужно rotateY

Answer (score 1):

```
    .product-card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200;
    perspective: 600;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.product-card:hover .product-card__flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.product-card:hover .product-card__back-side {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.product-card__flipper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.product-card__front-side, .product-card__back-side {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.product-card__front-side {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.product-card__back-side {
      display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: -2;
}

.product-card__title {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```